# Using Asynchronous Methods in Entity Framework's ValidateEnity Method

Tags: entity-framework, validation, asynchronous

I am trying to override the EnityFramework's DbContext.ValidateEntity() method in Entity Framework 6.

The problem I have is that I need to call FirstOrDefaultAsync() in my validation logic, but this causes me a problem with the override as the method is not marked asynchronous.  Here is the code I have so far...

```
protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity ( 
  DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items) 
{ 
    var result = new DbEntityValidationResult(
        entityEntry, new List<DbValidationError>()); 

    if (entityEntry.Entity is Post && entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added) 
    { 
        Post post = entityEntry.Entity as Post;

        // This line is illegal as the ValidateEntity()
        // method is not asynchronous
        var errors = await ValidatePost(post);

        // error processing here..
    } 

    if (result.ValidationErrors.Count > 0)  
    { 
        return result; 
    } 
    else  
    { 
        return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items); 
    } 
}


public async Task<ICollection<DbValidationError>>
ValidatePost(Post post)
{
   var errors = new List<DbValidationError>();

   Post temp = await this.DbContext.Posts
       .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Title == entity.Title);

   if ((temp != null) && (temp.Id != entity.Id))
   {
       errors.Add(new DbValidationError(
          "Title", "A Post already exists with the title " + temp.Title
       ));
   }

   return errors;
}
```

The actual validation logic shown above is somewhat simplified, but it demonstrates the problem.

How can I call .FirstOrDefaultsAsync(), or any entity framework asynchronous methods from within the ValidateEntity/non-asynchronous method?

Comment: You would have to block, which negates the benefits of the async calls inside `ValidatePost()`. Why not just use the synchronous versions of the EF calls inside?

Comment: I couldn't find the synchronous version .FirstOrDefault() - I assumed it had been removed?

Comment: Be sure you bring in the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Thanks Anthony - I was being stupid and relied on the intellisense too much without engaging my brain!